# Jison Lex without white spaces

Tags: flex-lexer, jison

I have this Jison lexer and parser:

```
%lex
%%

\s+              /* skip whitespace */
'D01'            return 'D01'
[xX][+-]?[0-9]+  return 'COORD'
<<EOF>>          return 'EOF'
.                return 'INVALID'

/lex

%start source
%%

source
: command EOF;

command
: D01 COORD;
```

It will tokenize and parse `D01 X45` but not `D01X45`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike (f)lex -- or, indeed, the vast majority of scanner generators, jison scanners do not implement the longest-match rule. Instead, the first matching pattern wins.

In order to make this work for keywords, jison scanners also implement the restriction that simple literal strings -- like "D01" -- only match if they end on a word-boundary.

The workaround is to enclose the literal string pattern with redundant parentheses:

```
("D01")       { return 'D01'; }
```

This is documented in the [jison wiki](https://github.com/zaach/jison/wiki/Deviations-From-Flex-Bison)